# Лайки и комментарии из Vk в colorbox

Tags: jquery, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, есть галерея изображений с эффектом colorbox, подскажите возможно ли вставить в раскрывающееся окно колобокс лайк для изображения и комментарии вконтакте?

а главное как это сделать....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вставить iframe'ом